# Blade if condition in controller function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Is it possible to use blade @if conditions in functions of controller. This is my function of PublicController

```
    public function tourBanner($country){

    @if( $country == 'country1')
        background-image:url({{ asset('images/inside8.jpg') }});                        
    @elseif ( $country == 'country2')           
            background-image:url({{ asset('images/inside7.jpg') }});

    @elseif ( $country == 'country3')           
            background-image:url({{ asset('images/inside5.jpg') }});

    @elseif ( $country == 'country4')           
            background-image:url({{ asset('images/inside6.jpg') }});            
    @else           
            background-image:url({{ asset('images/inside10.jpg') }});           
    @endif

    return banner;
}
```

And i'm getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)
```

What mistake i have made or we can't use blade if if statements in controller ?

Comment: The mistake you made is using blade syntax in regular PHP file. Use PHP syntax.

Comment: @zachary, you can use `@if` in your blade, not in the controller. did you check @devmyb's answer?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of Blade `@if` is made for using in blade views not into the php files (as in your case controllers). You should use Blade Syntax in to files ending with extension - filename.**blade.php**, and in you controller please use normal PHP syntax for if statement.

Please see [Blade Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

```
class Controller {
   function a() {
      if($country == 'country1') {
          $asset_str = asset('images/inside8.jpg');
          $banner = "background-image:url({$asset_str})";
      }
      ....
      return $banner;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Typos within your code that code is meant for blade files and not for your PHP files. Listing issues within your code

Remove `@` from your code

```
@if .... @elsif
```

should be

```
if .... elseif
```

better for multiple `if ... else` you can use `switch case`

You were returning `banner` but it should be `$banner` and also you were not assigning any value to `$banner` variable. So your code be like as

```
if( $country == 'country1')
       $banner =  "background-image:url(".asset('images/inside8.jpg') .")";
.......

return $banner;
```

better to use `switch case` like as

```
switch($country)
{
     case "country1":
          $banner =  "background-image:url(".asset('images/inside8.jpg') .")";
          break;
     case ..............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you should write like this:

```
if ($country == 'country1') {
    $a = 'background-image:url('.asset('images/inside8.jpg').')';
} elseif ....
```

But if you're gonna to build HTML/CSS/JS with PHP, it's terrible idea, do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try switch case for above condition.

```
switch ($country) {
    case "country1":
        echo "background-image:url({{ asset('images/inside8.jpg') }})";
        break;
}
```

It will return exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

> You could build up the style within your controller and then pass the resulting data to your view from that Controller and then render it. This snippet may give you a little insight:

```
<?php

    public function tourBanner($country){
        $extraData  = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];

        switch($country){
            case 'country1':
                $bgImage    = 'images/inside8.jpg';
                break;
            case 'country2':
                $bgImage    = 'images/inside7.jpg';
                break;
            case 'country3':
                $bgImage    = 'images/inside5.jpg';
                break;
            case 'country4':
                $bgImage    = 'images/inside6.jpg';
                break;
            default:
                $bgImage    = 'images/inside10.jpg';
                break;
        }

        return view("your.blade.view", array(
            "bgImage"    => $bgImage,
            'extraData'  => $extraData,
        ));
    }
```

> Then; in the View, it would be a matter of doing something like this:

```
    <div class="container" style="background-image:url({{ asset($bgImage) }})">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Some Content...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

NO, you cant. just use the default `if else` condition in php.

Answer (score 0):

Blade is a template parser, which converts code to PHP behind the scenes.
If you want to use some if statement in your controller you just use the standard IF statement.

```
if($q == $a) {
    #more code here
} else {
    $other code here
}
```

As suggested above, it's recommended using a switch statement when using a lot of else statements for your if

```
switch($q){
    case "yes": 
        return $something;
    break;
    case "no":
        return $somethingelse;
        break;
    case "maybe":
        return $whoknows;
        break;
}
```