# Jquery ui slider with ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-5.3

I am trying to use jquery ui (range) slider with ajax, to filter products according to price range from user. Jquery ui slider, routes and controller are arranged correctly but ajax is not connecting them. Below are my codes:

Slider html code:

```
<h4>Filter by:</h4>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
```

Html code were i want change with ajax:

```
@foreach( $proucts as $product)
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
   <img src="{{$product->image}}">
   <p>{{$product->name}}-{{$product->price}}</p>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Jquery slider function with ajax

```
$( function() {
  $( "#price-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 3500,
    values: [ 75, 1500 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      var value1 = ui.values[0];
      var value2 = ui.values[1];

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "price.filter",
        data: "value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          $('public.products.list');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#price-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#price-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

My route:

```
Route::get('filterprice/{min}/{max}', 
          ['as' => 'price.filter',
          'uses' => 'PublicController@filterPrice']);
```

My method in controller:

```
public function filterPrice($min, $max)
{
    $filter = DB::table('products')
                ->whereBetween('price', 
                 [use($min), use($max)])
                ->get();

     return view('public.products.list')->withTours($filter);
}
```

I would be very thank full if anyone could share idea about this.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with your code, all of which point to the same underlying issue, which explains the problems you are having in this question *as well as a number of other recent questions you have asked*.

Your problem is that you do not understand the separation between the different types of code with which you are working. In the code for this question, you freely mix the PHP code you have written for Laravel *which runs on the server*, with the JavaScript code you have written for jQuery *which runs in the web browser*. In the code for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40815754/829970), you mix the Laravel template language `blade` into regular PHP code.

In order to avoid having future similar problems, you need to pay more attention to what types of code belong where and how those different pieces of code can interact with each other.

---

First, jQuery doesn't know about the route names in Laravel, so your AJAX call isn't going to the correct URL. You also aren't properly providing the parameters to the URL.

There are many potential ways you can fix this, but I'll just give you one of them

Instead of sending `min` and `max` as part of the "path" portion of the URL, send them as query strings.

### Route

```
Route::get('filterprice', 
      ['as' => 'price.filter',
      'uses' => 'PublicController@filterPrice']);
```

### JavaScript

```
$( function() {
  $( "#price-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 3500,
    values: [ 75, 1500 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      var value1 = ui.values[0];
      var value2 = ui.values[1];

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "filterprice",
        data: "min="+value1+"&max="+value2,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
          $('public.products.list');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#price-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#price-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

### Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function filterPrice(Request $request)
{
    // You should also add input validation here.

    $filter = DB::table('products')
                ->whereBetween('price', 
                 [$request->input('min'), $request->input('max')])
                ->get();

     return view('public.products.list')->withTours($filter);
}
```

---

Second, you are never filling the results of the AJAX call back into the page.  Your code says only `$('public.products.list');` in the `success` function, which does nothing useful. (What it actually does is look for HTML elements that looks like `<public class="products list"></public>` and returns an array of pointers to it them, which is clearly not what you are trying to do.)

Assuming that your results on the page are wrapped by `<div id="productList">...</div>`, here is what you need the `success` function in your JavaScript to look like:

```
success: function(html) {
    $("#productList").html(html);
}
```

Comment: This is useful. Cool.